# C# absolute path with streamReader

Tags: c#, relative-path, streamreader, filereader, absolute-path

I have an issue with the reading a file in C#
I have two different locations for .exe (both different) and reading the same .xml file. So when I give the path like this:

```
TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(@"../../../TrajectoryGen/obstacleList.xml");
```

it is able to read from one location ( which is 3 folders behind as used in the path) but not from another location (which is only 2 folders behind)
How do I fix this problem so that it works from both folders?

Comment: `@"../../../TrajectoryGen/obstacleList.xml"` for one and `@"../../TrajectoryGen/obstacleList.xml"` for the other? That's "how you fix this problem" - or did you have a different question?

Comment: Dude, it is the same problem, but not so easy. There are two different GUI accessing exactly the same code from different folders. so I cannot define different path objects for the two GUI as they are using the same path object.

Comment: It sounds like you have more of an architectural problem. We'd have to see your entire project, which would probably be too big a question. You might want to consider opening a question on [SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/), asking how to organize your code so that you can access dynamically placed files, or something.

Comment: Yeah. But the problem is that I cannot restructure the code as it is a part of a big project.So, I was wondering if it could be fixed using some kind of a solution reference to the path?

Comment: You'd have to use some kind of code that could read folder names and walk up the hierarchy, or have a config file with the absolute path, or put the desired file in a [system location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx). Again, though, this is architectural stuff - not really a [good fit](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) for SO.

Answer (score 0):

First way, this relies on you knowing one of the parent folder's names.

```
const string FILENAME = "obstacleList.xml";
const string FOLDER = "TrajectoryGen";

string path = Path.GetFullPath(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
do
{
     path = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
} while (!Path.GetFileName(path).Equals(FOLDER, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
string filepath = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", path, Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, FILENAME);
```

^^ You can also use a partial path in the FILENAME like the example below incase you need to into directories once you are at your "base" folder that you know the name of.

Second way blindly continues up directories

```
const string FILENAME = @"TrajectoryGen\obstacleList.xml";

string path = Path.GetFullPath(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

string filepath;

do
{
    path = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);

    //pump
    filepath = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", path, Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, FILENAME);
} while (!File.Exists(filepath));
```

Both require "using System.IO;" and both have no error handling implemented and will throw NullReferenceException if the file/folder is not found.

I purposely used the do-while loop because the definition of path will included the executable name.